# ASP.NET Core RenderingHost in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, jss

I'm currently testing Sc10 with ASP.NET Core Rendering Host from the following [Getting Started documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html).

So far the rendering host works fine but whenever I want to access the Experience Editor I get an internal server error 500.
I tried to debug the rendering host which works but throws errors in some code I can't locate. (Without any customizations).
Does anyone had the same issues?

```
Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.RenderEngine.Invoke[T](String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.PerformRender(TextWriter writer, IRenderEngine renderEngine, String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

Comment: Please include the exception as plain text. Search Engines can't scan your screencaps.

Answer (score 3):

This was an issue in the initial release of the ASP.NET Core SDK (14.0.0). It is resolved in 14.0.1, which is referenced in version 1.0.1 of `Sitecore.DevEx.Templates`.

To install latest template:

```
dotnet new -i Sitecore.DevEx.Templates --nuget-source https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json
```

If you have an existing template instance, you can upgrade the packages in the RenderingHost.csproj manually, or by doing something like this:

```
([xml](gc .\RenderingHost.csproj -Raw)).GetElementsByTagName("PackageReference") | ? { $_.Include.StartsWith("Sitecore") } | % { dotnet add package $_.Include }
```